# Integrar un buscador en JavaScript con la paginación de Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, paginación, buscador

mi problema es que intento integrar un buscador de JavaScript con la propia paginación de Laravel. Aquí les dejo todo lo que he conseguido hasta el momento.

```js
//Variables globales
var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;

function myFunction() {
  
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  
  ocultarAnimacion();

  tr = table.querySelectorAll("tr:nth-child(odd)");
 
  
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}

//Me oculta la animación del archivo animate.css del listado.
function ocultarAnimacion(){

  tr = table.querySelectorAll("tr:nth-child(even)");
  for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    var clase = tr[i].classList;
    if(clase.item(5) === 'show'){
      tr[i].className = 'collapse in slideInLeft animated trEsconder';
    }
  }
}
```

Como podéis ver, intento de que alguna manera el buscador de JavaScript recoja todo los datos, que le paso desde el controlador de Laravel a la vista con el paginate. He conseguido hacerlo solo en la página donde esté el usuario pero no 
con todos los datos. ¿Alguna sugerencia o ayuda?.

Comment: Como sugerencia, mirate un pluging llamado "Datatable" o la dependencia para laravel "yajra/laravel-datatables"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hola te recomiendo utilizar datatables ya que ya trae implementado el paginador, sort y buscador.

https://datatables.net/

Otra opción es que utilices la función keypress en Javascript para llamar a tu función PHP por medio de un AJAX y le pases el parámetro de búsqueda en donde tu consulta tendrá habilitado un LIKE sobre una columna o columnas especificas.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas después de un tiempo pensando que hacer... me decante por usar Ajax de JS con Laravel y crear una tabla secundaria por DOM en la misma página que me mostrara los resultados obtenidos . De todas formas gracias por las sugerencias.